# ES6 looping with async call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I need to write some Javascript (ES6 version) to perform the following task:

1. the string is "item1,item2,item3,item4,item5",
2. fetch() an URL using this string.
3. if the response flag is a success, done and exit.
4. if the response flag is a fail, drop the last item (item5) so now the string is "item1,item2,item3,item4" and repeat step 2.
5. if no more item to drop, exit.

The total number of items is variable. So I plan to perform this task using a do-loop, using the following structure:

```
//suppose str = 'item1,item2,item3,....itemN'
do {
    fetch(url, {param1: str}).then(response => {
        //check the response flag, if success, done and exit.
        //if not success, drop one item and re-do fetch
    })
}
```

The problem is that the fetch is an async call so I cannot force each fetch executed in a sequence.

I need to make sure a new fetch() only executed when the previous fetch() fail. Any ideas?

Comment: `function doFetch() {  if (arr.length>0)  fetch(url, {param1: arr.pop()}).then(response => {
        if (!success) doFetch();
    })`

Comment: Can you use ES8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use recursion:

```
function fetchRecursive(param) {

  return fetch(url, {param1: param})
    .then(response => response.ok ? response : Promise.reject(new Error(response.status)))
    .catch((err) => {
      if (param.length > 1) {
        return fetchRecursive(param.slice(0,-1));
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    })
}

fetchRecursive([ 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4' ])
  .then(response => { ... })
  .catch(err => { ... });
```

Comment: (Using the HTML5 `fetch` API instead of some arbitrary `fetch` function, it would need to be `fetch(…).then(response => response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(new Error(response.status))).catch(…)` or so, but +1 for the generic approach)

Comment: You're right. Also, my code wasn't entirely correct. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use recurrsion, something like this:

```
//str = 'item1,item2,item3,....itemN'
function fetchUrl(str){
  fetch(url, {param1: str}).then(response => {
        if(response.success){
          //exit from the program
          return response;
        }
        else
        {
          return fetchUrl(str.split(",").pop().join(","));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `await` instead of `then` in a for loop

Comment: A bit more of explanation on the differences of them, and why it matters, would be helpful!